# "食人" in Classical Chinese of the 先秦 period

Tags: classical-chinese, verbs

I'd like to know whether "食人" is used in Classical Chinese of the 先秦 period. I am not looking for "食人肉."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the book of mencius 孟子, chapter 梁惠王上:

> 此率獸而**食人**也

roughly means

> This is leading on beasts to devour men.

https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=gb&id=12876#s10026702

in the same book, chapter 滕文公上:

> 治於人者**食人**，治人者食於人

roughly means

> those who are governed by others support them; those who govern others are supported by them

https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=gb&id=13261#s10030257

have fun :)

Comment: Could you find more examples of "食人" used literally to mean "eat people"?